# How do you create a pointer to a struct and type cast it?

Tags: objective-c, c, oop

can someone tell me where I'm going wrong here? I'm trying to create a pointer to the struct aqData that is passed in to the function, and type type cast it to a struct type of AQPlayerState.

I'm getting the errors - Use of undeclared identifier "AQPlayerState" and Expected expression

```
    @implementation AudioPlayer

#define kNumberBuffers 3

struct AQPlayerState {
    AudioStreamBasicDescription   mDataFormat;
    AudioQueueRef                 mQueue;
    AudioQueueBufferRef           mBuffers[kNumberBuffers];
    AudioFileID                   mAudioFile;
    UInt32                        bufferByteSize;
    SInt64                        mCurrentPacket;
    UInt32                        mNumPacketsToRead;
    AudioStreamPacketDescription  *mPacketDescs;
    bool                          mIsRunning;
};

static void HandleOutputBuffer (
                                void                *aqData,
                                AudioQueueRef       inAQ,
                                AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer
                                ) {

    struct AQPlayerState *pAqData = (AQPlayerState *) aqData;
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: And what is your error message?

Comment: Ah, sorry bout that, post edited

Answer (score 3):

*I believe `Objective-C` behaves as `C`. If it doesn't this might not apply to `Objective-C`.*

structs in C are recognized by their "full name". <s>Try</s>

```
    struct AQPlayerState *pAqData = (struct AQPlayerState *) aqData;
```

or, **even better**, don't cast at all. The C compiler knows how to convert from `void*` to any other pointer to object

```
    struct AQPlayerState *pAqData = aqData;
```

- implicit conversion: **good**
- explicit conversion (cast): not so good